# Is there a good HTML template engine in cocoa touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, template-engine

In my iphone app, I want to populate UIWebView with some html generated from a templates.
Is there a good opensource template engine library for cocoa touch like jinja or smarty?

Comment: yup. too many results = no results.. i am looking for the best available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [MGTemplateEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa).

Comment: Thanks. started using this. The only thing i miss here is file inclusions. I cannot include a template inside another template.

Comment: @Rajani it might be possible to write an addon for that. From what I've read about extending the engine, it looked quite simple.

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/groue/GRMustache is a full implementation of the {{ mustache }} template engine.